# How to execute command when holding a book?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Well, I was playing on a Creative Plots server today, and I noticed this particular book. When you held it, it killed you. I know there must have been some hacks involved, but how was it done? I think NBT was involved, so is there a tag that would make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a scoreboard dummy variable for anybody holding the book, like so;

> /scoreboard objectives add holding.killbook dummy

Next, add a scoreboard variable for deaths, to reset the previous variable;

> /scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount

Then, put these three commands (in this order) on a repeating command string;

> /scoreboard players set @a holding.killbook 1 {SelectedItem:{id:**id**,tag:{**put any other NBT tags in here**}}}
>
> /kill @a[score_holding.killbook_min=1]
>
> /scoreboard players set @a[score_deaths_min=1] holding.killbook 0

Comment: How can  you set holding.killbook if the player is dead? Wouldn't holding.killbook always be set to 1 once a player holds the killbook? (I'm assuming all three command blocks operate in the same tick)

Comment: A variable can be set to a player regardless of whether they are dead or not